# Retrieving a value from mysqli query, and assigning it to a php variable

Tags: php, mysqli, fetch

I am getting the ID of the last row inserted into the mysql database.

I want to fetch the ID and assign to a php variable I can use else where in the script.

I would prefer the most versatile method of doing this. So something along the lines of a mysqli_fetch_all (BOTH).

I can't seem to do this without while looping the results. Is there a cleaner way?

```
    $query = "SELECT ID FROM Title
    ORDER BY ID DESC
    LIMIT 1";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

    //Get the result and bind it to a php variable that can be used 
    //in another part of the script

    //free result
    //?
    //close statement
    $stmt->close();
```

Comment: Well, if you know exactly what's retrieved you could potentially do `$variable = $result->arayBranch->valueYouWant`. Without looping.